# How can I change a string twice (building on the previous changes) in Java? (code inside)

Tags: java, string

for example, say I have a string called names and I want to .toUpperCase and then use the .replaceAll function before printing it.

The problem I'm having is that only one step is applied at a time and the two functions are handled separately.

```
    System.out.format(names[i].toUpperCase());
        System.out.format(names[i].replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>"));
        System.out.println(names[i]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `System.out.println( names[i].toUpperCase().replaceAll("SMITH, "<>JENKINS<>"));` not work?

Answer (score 3):

`.toUpperCase()` returns a `String`. You need to something like:

```
names[i].toUpperCase().replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>");
```

or

```
names[i] = names[i].toUpperCase();
names[i].replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Strings are immutable in java, none of these functions work in-place. They don't change `names[i]`. So you'd have assign them to a temp variable (or `names[i]`). Do something like this.

```
    String tmp = names[i].toUpperCase();
    System.out.format(tmp);
    tmp = tmp.replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>")
    System.out.format(tmp);
    System.out.println(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain method calls, since `String` instances are immutable and each method returns the string as transformed by its operations.

```
String changed = names[i].toUpperCase().replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>");
System.out.format(changed);
```

The variable `changed` has been extracted to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`String`s in Java are immutable, they do not change themselves. The methods you use return a new, changed string:

```
names[i] = names[i].toUpperCase();
System.out.format(names[i]);
names[i] = names[i]..replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>");
System.out.format(names[i]);
```

does what you expected your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
names[i].replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>")
```

this code only returs the replaced string. you need to set it to a variable;

`string str = names[i].replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>");`

or to replace the current reference;

`names[i]= names[i].replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>");`

Answer (score 0):

Extract a variable?

```
    String str = names[i].toUpperCase().replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(names[i].toUpperCase().replaceAll("SMITH", "<>JENKINS<>"));
```